# How to show default value in control grid in a repositoryitemlookupedit column?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, gridcontrol, repositorylookupedit

I linked a datasource table to the control grid:

[image]

and all the data from the table are shown successfuly exept the "Type" column that I assigned to a "RepositoryItemLookupEdit" to choose the types from a list. As seen in the screenshot, the displayed member and the value member properties are set correctly. After selecting a type from the RepositoryItemLookupEdit, the selected one remains shown on the grid (when selecting another cell). So my problem is that I want to display the initial values in the "Type" column.

Comment: You can either set the value in your table to be the default value, which you can also do with the query for your data (depending on your source. If you just want to show something visually without having to change the data, you can use the "Null Text" property to show something when nothing is set. Then you have to assume a null is a default elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the `CustomDisplayText` of the RepositoryItem

If your 'Type' column is bound to a dataobject such as...

```
public class SomeType
    public property Name as string
    public property Description as string   
    public property Code as string  
End Class
```

You need to populate the `DisplayText` of the cell with the value of the cell.

```
Private Sub RepositoryItem_CustomDisplayText(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CustomDisplayTextEventArgs) Handles RepositoryItemLookUpEdit1.CustomDisplayText
    Try
        Dim currentSomeType = TryCast(e.Value, SomeType)
        If Not currentSomeType Is Nothing Then
            'find the correct SomeType
            Dim currentSomeTypeName As String = currentSomeType.Name
            e.DisplayText = currentSomeTypeName
        End If
    Catch exception As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

From ColumnEdit select DisplayMember select your field

[First][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoVZO.png

[Second][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLMdW.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).